# System of equations and the Brouwer's Fixed-Point Theorem.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, systems-of-equations, fixed-point-theorems

Let's consider the following system of equations:
\begin{eqnarray}{
e^{xyz}  =  \frac{x}{\sqrt{e^{2xyz}+1}}\\
\cos(x+y+z)  =  \frac{y}{\sqrt{e^{2xyz}+1}}\\
\sin(x+y+z)  =  \frac{z}{\sqrt{e^{2xyz}+1}}
}\end{eqnarray}

Does this system have a solution?

The idea is to use the Brouwer's fixed-point theorem. If we consider the continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^3$ defined by
$$f(x,y,z)=(e^{xyz}\sqrt{e^{2xyz}+1},\cos(x+y+z)\sqrt{e^{2xyz}+1},\sin(x+y+z) \sqrt{e^{2xyz}+1}),$$

then it is enough to find a subspace $A$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$, homeomorphic to $D^3$ such that $f(A)\subset A$. Then by the  Brouwer's fixed-point theorem, the function will have a fixed point in $A$, the one which will be our solution. But finding a suitable $A$ hasn't been an easy task for me. Probably I have to modify the function $f$ a little but I'm out of ideas.

Comment: We have $\lVert f(x,y,z) \rVert = e^{2xyz} + 1 \ge 2$. This shows that there is no closed ball $B = B_r(0)$ such that $f(B) \subset B$ (taking $(x,y,z) = (r/\sqrt{3},r/\sqrt{3},r/\sqrt{3}) \in B$, we get $\lVert f(x,y,z) \rVert =e^{2r^3/3\sqrt{3}} + 1 > r$). This does not exclude that there are other $A$ which behave better, but I doubt it. Modifying $f$ is no option because we would get solutions of a different system of equations.

Comment: Have you tried to find the argmin of $\|f(x,y,z) - \textrm{id}\|$ over $\mathbb{R}^3$?  I don't have any numerical solvers available right this minute but such an approach might prove amenable for a specific functional form such as this.